# Validating JWT claims using nimbus jose-jwt (java)

Tags: java, jwt, nimbus-jose-jwt

I am using nimbus jost+jwt version 8.19 in a normal java project (not using spring). I have some claims such as iss, aud and sub and want to validate them. (I want iss, aud and sub to be a specific value). I want the parser to throw an exception when the claims dont match.
The example provided [here](https://connect2id.com/products/nimbus-jose-jwt/examples/validating-jwt-access-tokens) worked fine in earlier versions , But it seems like it was changed in later versions.

Earlier (version 8.3) I used to validate using the following code

```
    JWKSet jwkSet = new JWKSet(utils.rsakey);
    JWKSource<SecurityContext> jwkSource = new ImmutableJWKSet<>(jwkSet);

    ConfigurableJWTProcessor<SecurityContext> jwtProcessor = new DefaultJWTProcessor<>();
    jwtProcessor.setJWSTypeVerifier(new DefaultJOSEObjectTypeVerifier<>(new JOSEObjectType("jwt")));

    JWSAlgorithm expectedJWSAlg = JWSAlgorithm.RS256;

    JWTClaimsSet validClaims= new JWTClaimsSet.Builder()
            .issuer(InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName()
            .subject("matchvalue")
            .audience("matchvalue")
            .build();

    JWSKeySelector<SecurityContext> keySelector =
            new JWSVerificationKeySelector<>(expectedJWSAlg, jwkSource);

    jwtProcessor.setJWTClaimsSetVerifier(new DefaultJWTClaimsVerifier(
            //exact match claims
            validClaims,
            //Required claims
            new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("exp", "sub","iss")))); 
    jwtProcessor.setJWSKeySelector(keySelector);

    // Process the token
    SecurityContext ctx = null; // optional context parameter, not required here
    JWTClaimsSet tokenClaims= jwtProcessor.process(token, ctx);
```

but now (version 8.19) the DefaultJWTClaimsVerifier does not seem to be accepting exact match claims and Required claims parameters. Is there any way to implement the exact match and required claims?

All of my imports for refrence

```
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.security.KeyPair;
import java.security.KeyPairGenerator;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashSet;

import javax.crypto.KeyGenerator;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.ws.rs.FormParam;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

import com.nimbusds.jose.EncryptionMethod;
import com.nimbusds.jose.JOSEException;
import com.nimbusds.jose.JOSEObjectType;
import com.nimbusds.jose.JWEAlgorithm;
import com.nimbusds.jose.JWEHeader;
import com.nimbusds.jose.JWEObject;
import com.nimbusds.jose.JWSAlgorithm;
import com.nimbusds.jose.JWSHeader;
import com.nimbusds.jose.JWSSigner;
import com.nimbusds.jose.KeyLengthException;
import com.nimbusds.jose.Payload;
import com.nimbusds.jose.crypto.DirectDecrypter;
import com.nimbusds.jose.crypto.RSAEncrypter;
import com.nimbusds.jose.crypto.RSASSASigner;
import com.nimbusds.jose.jwk.JWKSet;
import com.nimbusds.jose.jwk.KeyUse;
import com.nimbusds.jose.jwk.RSAKey;
import com.nimbusds.jose.jwk.gen.RSAKeyGenerator;
import com.nimbusds.jose.jwk.source.ImmutableJWKSet;
import com.nimbusds.jose.jwk.source.JWKSource;
import com.nimbusds.jose.proc.BadJOSEException;
import com.nimbusds.jose.proc.DefaultJOSEObjectTypeVerifier;
import com.nimbusds.jose.proc.JWSKeySelector;
import com.nimbusds.jose.proc.JWSVerificationKeySelector;
import com.nimbusds.jose.proc.SecurityContext;
import com.nimbusds.jwt.JWTClaimsSet;
import com.nimbusds.jwt.SignedJWT;
import com.nimbusds.jwt.proc.ConfigurableJWTProcessor;
import com.nimbusds.jwt.proc.DefaultJWTClaimsVerifier;
import com.nimbusds.jwt.proc.DefaultJWTProcessor;
```